# Swift Regex with special Characters

Tags: ios, swift, regex, special-characters

I am attempting to use this string:

```
var passwordRegex = "^[A-Za-z0-9 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~].{8,}$"
```

As my regular expression pattern, but it keeps failing saying the pattern is invalid. I used the `\` character to escape for the characters: `"` and `\`, but it throws the error: `invalid escape sequence in literal` for regex key characters like `^ & [ ] | .` etc.

What am I missing in order to allow the characters:

```
 ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

(including space) in my regex? I assume it's something with how I am escaping, but I can't find anything anywhere for these characters in regards to SWIFT's regular expression.

Comment: A useful method is [`NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1408386-escapedpattern)

Comment: It's pretty standard to limit the character's that are allowed in a password if you want to properly encrypt the password. Unless you plan to write an encryptor that handles every single possible character in the world (Chinese symbols, Arabic symbols, etc.)

Comment: Since you are going to be encrypting data obtained from the string, why does any particular character have anything to do with the ability to encrypt the password?

Comment: You know, I’m not entirely for sure. But I do know it’s very common to limit what characters a user can use for a password. I dont know why you guys even care, you’re getting off topic now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that characters `[`, `\`, and `]` need to be escaped because they have special meaning in a regular expression.

So you need `\[`, `\\`, and `\]` in the regular expression. But since this is inside a Swift string, each `\` needs to be escaped with a `\`.

So `[\]` becomes `\[\\\]` in the regular expression which becomes `\\[\\\\\\]` in the Swift string.

The final valid string is:

```
var passwordRegex = "^[A-Za-z0-9 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\\[\\\\\\]^_`{|}~].{8,}$"
```

Comment: Ahh, escape the escape. Makes sense. Haha, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: _Escapeception_. Once again, @rmaddy saves the day :-)